# How can I write a web service in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms, asp.net-ajax, umbraco

I wrote a web service in my project for submitting a form but it doesn't work. I've used Umbraco CMS 6.1.5.

Descriptions:

I wrote in **Master.master**:

```
<form id="AbniyehMainForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
            EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Auto">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/ApplicationFormService.asmx" />
            </Services>
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/building.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
```

I wrote in **ApplicationFormService.asmx**:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ApplicationFormService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I wrote in **ApplicationFormControl.ascx.cs**:

```
[WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static void HelloWorld()
    {
        ApplicationFormService s = new ApplicationFormService();
        s.HelloWorld();
    }
```

I wrote in **default.aspx**:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Defraz.Building.WebApp.Services" %>

<script runat="server" type="text/C#" language="c#">
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static string HelloWorld()
{
    return "HelloWorld!!!";
}
</script>
```

I wrote in **Building.js**:

```
function btnSendApplicationForm_onclick() {
     PageMethods.HelloWorld(_onMethodComplete, _onMethodError);
}

function _onMethodComplete(result) {
    alert(result.message);
}

function _onMethodError(result) {
    alert(result._message);
}
```

When the code was running the PageMethods.HelloWorld(_onMethodComplete, _onMethodError), I received an error form  _onMethodError that tell me

> "The server method 'HelloWorld' failed."

PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using v6.x could you use Umbraco WebAPI implementation? So instead of creating a webservice, create a WebAPI controller/action as per this article: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/

The advantage of this is that you get access to all the Umbraco context and services directly from the controller.

Obviously this means that you wouldn't necessarily get the benefits of the `webmethod` but you could still do much of your work in the if you return json and deserialize it to a strong type you can then work with.

Comment: I've used ASP.NET Web Form. I think it's not possible to use WebAPI.

Comment: It is. If you are using v6 you can actually use masterpages and mvc and web api all in the same project. I often use the WebAPI to set up an API specifically for calling from js files to provide JSON data, regardless of whether the js is loaded by a webform or mvc view.

Answer (score 0):

WebMethods cannot be in usercontrols. I'd recommend using a webservice (.asmx) and place your webmethod there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you write a web service in Umbraco, - sounds like you're trying to co-locate one with Umbraco. Why not add a Service Reference to an existing web service? Alternatively include the WebApi libs in your Umbraco solution and make a Restful call.